# What does * mean as a parameter in python?

Tags: python, parameters, arguments

I was browsing through [this file of code](https://github.com/Just-Some-Bots/MusicBot/blob/master/musicbot/entry.py#L251) and then I found this class:

```
class StreamPlaylistEntry(BasePlaylistEntry):
def __init__(self, playlist, url, title, *, destination=None, **meta):
    super().__init__()
```

I know that an asterisk in front of a parameter means it's a list of an arbitrary number of arguments, but what does the asterisk by itself mean?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It means all arguments afterwards are keyword-only. As said in the [official glossary under the word **parameter**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter):

> - *keyword-only:* specifies an argument that can be supplied only by
>   keyword. Keyword-only parameters can be defined by including a single
>   var-positional parameter or bare `*` in the parameter list of the
>   function definition before them, for example *kw_only1* and *kw_only2* in
>   the following:
>
>   ```
>    def func(arg, *, kw_only1, kw_only2): ...
>   ```

---

This allows you to force the users of your code (which may include yourself) to be more explicit. Compare:

```py
def f(x, y, allow_zero=True, some_other_flag=False, bonus=0): ...

f(2, 0, False, True, 100)  # valid
f(2, 0, allow_zero=False, some_other_flag=True, bonus=100)  # valid
```

with

```py
def f(x, y, *, allow_zero=True, some_other_flag=False, bonus=0): ...

f(2, 0, False, True, 100)  # TypeError: f() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
f(2, 0, allow_zero=False, some_other_flag=True, bonus=100)  # valid
```

Comment: could you give some use cases for the keyword-only parameters?

Comment: Note that with the first definition, both calls are equivalent. With the second definition, *only* the second call is valid; the first would produce a `TypeError` since there are too many positional arguments.