# TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given (Text Analysis with Python)

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp

I was trying to follow https://github.com/foxbook/atap/blob/master/snippets/ch04/loader.py but having the below error:

**TypeError: **init**() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given**
Any thoughts on how to resolve the error

I was able to make changes and run PickledCorpusReader but Corpus Loader is giving some issues as shared below.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold


class CorpusLoader(object):
    """
    The corpus loader knows how to deal with an NLTK corpus at the top of a
    pipeline by simply taking as input a corpus to read from. It exposes both
    the data and the labels and can be set up to do cross-validation.
    If a number of folds is passed in for cross-validation, then the loader
    is smart about how to access data for train/test splits. Otherwise it will
    simply yield all documents in the corpus.
    """

    def __init__(self, corpus, folds=None, shuffle=True):
        self.n_docs = len(corpus.fileids())
        self.corpus = corpus
        self.folds  = folds
        self.shuffle = True

        if folds is not None:
            # Generate the KFold cross validation for the loader.
            self.folds = KFold(self.n_docs, folds, shuffle)

    @property
    def n_folds(self):
        """
        Returns the number of folds if it exists; 0 otherwise.
        """
        if self.folds is None: return 0
        return self.folds.n_folds

    def fileids(self, fold=None, train=False, test=False):
        """
        Returns a listing of the documents filtering to retreive specific
        data from the folds/splits. If no fold, train, or test is specified
        then the method will return all fileids.
        If a fold is specified (should be an integer between 0 and folds),
        then the loader will return documents from that fold. Further, train
        or test must be specified to split the fold correctly.
        """
        if fold is None:
            # If no fold is specified, return all the fileids.
            return self.corpus.fileids()

        # Otherwise, identify the fold specifically and get the train/test idx
        for fold_idx, (train_idx, test_idx) in enumerate(self.folds):
            if fold_idx == fold: break
        else:
            # We have discovered no correct fold.
            raise ValueError(
                "{} is not a fold, specify an integer less than {}".format(
                    fold, self.folds.n_folds
                )
            )

        # Now determine if we're in train or test mode.
        if not (test or train) or (test and train):
            raise ValueError(
                "Please specify either train or test flag"
            )

        # Select only the indices to filter upon.
        indices = train_idx if train else test_idx
        return [
            fileid for doc_idx, fileid in enumerate(self.corpus.fileids())
            if doc_idx in indices
        ]

    def labels(self, fold=None, train=False, test=False):
        """
        Fit will load a list of the labels from the corpus categories.
        If a fold is specified (should be an integer between 0 and folds),
        then the loader will return documents from that fold. Further, train
        or test must be specified to split the fold correctly.
        """
        return [
            self.corpus.categories(fileids=fileid)[0]
            for fileid in self.fileids(fold, train, test)
        ]

    def documents(self, fold=None, train=False, test=False):
        """
        A generator of documents being streamed from disk. Each document is
        a list of paragraphs, which are a list of sentences, which in turn is
        a list of tuples of (token, tag) pairs. All preprocessing is done by
        NLTK and the CorpusReader object this object wraps.
        If a fold is specified (should be an integer between 0 and folds),
        then the loader will return documents from that fold. Further, train
        or test must be specified to split the fold correctly. This method
        allows us to maintain the generator properties of document reads.
        """
        for fileid in self.fileids(fold, train, test):
            yield list(self.corpus.tagged(fileids=fileid))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from reader import PickledCorpusReader

    corpus4 = PickledCorpusReader(nomi,r'.+\.txt')
    loader = CorpusLoader(corpus, folds=12)

    for fid in loader.fileids(0):
        print(fid)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had an error with KFold as well. Specifying the keyword-arguments explicitly, like so:

```
self.folds = KFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle=shuffle)
```

resolved it for me. I do not know why, though.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @lucas.. i tried the following : class CorpusLoader(object):
    

    def __init__(self, corpus, folds=None, shuffle=True):
        self.n_docs = len(corpus.fileids())
        self.corpus = corpus
        self.folds  = folds
        self.shuffle = True

        if folds is not None:
            # Generate the KFold cross validation for the loader.
            self.folds = KFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle=shuffle)  and now getting error: TypeError: 'KFold' object is not iterable. Anything i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

When you get this kind of error "TypeError: init() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given" it means that called function requires at least some named arguments.
KFold is declared
class KFold(
n_splits: Int = 5,
*,
shuffle: bool = False,
random_state: Int | RandomState | None = None
)

If there is * in function declaration, parameters after * have to be named.

There is good explanation here
[What does * mean as a parameter in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362773/what-does-mean-as-a-parameter-in-python)

So only first parameter in KFold does not have to be named, second and third have to be named.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error as well, and I solve it by the following code:

```
KFold(n_splits=2, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
```

based on this link:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html